# Vite react typescript error in tsconfig.json

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

I am facing an error in `tsconfig.json` when I try to install React with TypeScript using Vite. Here's the line where I am facing error.

```
/* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
```

The same codebase works well on my colleague's PC, but I am facing this issue.

To resolve the issue, I changed my TypeScript version from 5.2.2 to 4.8. I also checked that my TypeScript is installed globally. but not working.

Comment: I am facing import issues. when I am importing something this shows me error like that `Cannot find module '../../components/atoms/toast'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?` . but other PC works well except  my PC.

Comment: Do you have a "components" folder two levels up from where you import it, which contains an "atoms" folder with a "toast.ts" file inside it?

Comment: yes, I have toast.tsx

Comment: Without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) here, there's not much we can use to help you. Please [edit] your question with that example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated VS Code 1.74.2 to the latest version 1.84.1 and this problem was solved.

Hope it helps you:)